# Why VC++ IntelliSense doesn't refresh error list?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

Why VC++ IntelliSense doesn't refresh error list?

There's an error in the code. IntelliSense shows it up. I fix it, and press F7 to re-compile, the compilation result is successful. But now IntelliSense doesn't refresh the error list, it still shows the former error, even after pressing 10 times F7 and F5 to start debugging.

That crazy IntelliSense error is still shown up. What happened with VC++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing your intellisense database file (.NCB file).
If the problem persists then you might have a too big project...

In my previous company we solved this by using intellisense of Visual Assist.(http://www.wholetomato.com/)

Too bad microsoft has a very unreliable intellisense database.

Comment: yes, because the project has so many lines of code, intellisense has to scan up and down, then up and down. i had to wait a few minutes